# because and comma in a relative clause

Tags: commas

> She's the only person who wasn't chosen because of her age.
>
> She's the only person who wasn't chosen, because of her age.

I feel like we shouldn't put a comma, because it's **wasn't chosen because of her age** is the clause that define who that person is, and because is not it's own clause. It completes the other clause and the meaning is not the same without because of her age. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are correct, but they have different meanings. In the first sentence everybody else was chosen because of their age, but she was chosen for a different reason. In the second sentence everybody else was chosen, but her age was the reason she was not chosen.